# How to determine the result type of a C++ lambda (Closure Type)

Tags: c++, lambda, functional-programming, c++14

I'm trying to write a template function that works with either a `std::function` or a lambda. Let's assume an `apply` template something like this:

```
template<typename F>
typename F::result_type apply(const F &f) {
    return f();
}
```

This is fine if I invoke it with a `std::function<int()>` for example, but not if a invoke it with `[]() -> int { return 1; }` because the lambda's closure type doesn't have a `result_type` member. So how do I write `apply`'s return type so it works properly?

I'm using clang 3.5 and C++14 at the moment, but whatever I get it'd be best if it was portable -- I'd be happy to switch to a newer compiler if that'd help.

The actual example is a bit more complex. I'm trying to write something like `reduce` that would apply arguments to a callable if the first argument is callable, otherwise it will ignore the arguments and return the value passed as the first argument.

```
reduce(0, 1, 2); // returns 0
reduce([](int a, int b) { return a+b; }, 2, 3); // return 5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For C++14, you should use `decltype(auto)`.

```
template<typename F>
decltype(auto) apply(const F &f) {
    return f();
}
```

For pre-C++14, you could use `result_type` from [`Boost.FunctionTypes`](http://www.boost.org/libs/function_types/).

```
template<typename F>
typename boost::function_types::result_type<F>::type apply(const F &f) {
    return f();
}
```

Comment: Aren't you missing a `::type` at the end of the Boost example? `typename boost::function_types::result_type<F>::type`

Comment: Why not a trailing return type with `decltype(f())` for pre-C++11 so there is no dependence on another library?

Comment: Because his question went on to say that it might not be as simple as a function with no arguments.

Comment: Turns out to be a little bit more complex, because I can't use `decltype(auto)` with `enable_if` and variadic arguments. I.e. this doesn't compile: `typename std::enable_if<is_callable<F>::value, decltype(auto)>::type apply(const F &f, const P &...ps)`

Comment: You could use a dummy template parameter for the SFINAE? Like `template <typename F, typename = typename std::enable_if<is_callable<F>::value>::type` and keep `decltype(auto)` by itself.

Comment: Ah, good idea. I actually just worked out a slightly different solution for myself -- use a forwarder that would pass an extra pointer argument to the actual implementation and have that pointer argument use the `enable_if`. Your solution sounds a bit cleaner though -- I'll give that a go.